# msbuild projects build order

Tags: msbuild, projects-and-solutions

I am building a solution in visual studio 2005, it is working fine but when I build it from msbuild some files do not get copied in start up projects bin folder. Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should add a reference to the projects which are required but not copied to bin folder. VS is more lenient about references then MSBuild is. If you have 3 projects A, B and C. A references B and B references C then you should add a reference to both B and C in project A.